# How to search in or sort finished quests?

Tags: pc, the-witcher-3

I would like to confirm that every finished quest is 100% completed (everything green, no red entries). But with every additional finished quest, the list get longer and more confusing.

How can I search in or sort finished quests?
What is the fastest way to find the last finished quest?

Comment: Being able to sort active quests by level would also be a welcome feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently (PC v1.06, 16/06/15) no way to filter or sort quests in the Journal, beyond the current categories (Completed, Side Quests, Witcher Contracts, Primary, Failed).

Comment: There is also a category for failed quests.

Comment: I also had a quick search to see if there were any mods doing this, and couldn't find anything. I'd hope it's possible, though it might be that the modding tools (RedKit) are more focused on in-game content rather than the interface.